# What did Elsie type at the first try?

Tags: the-world-god-only-knows

On first episode of The World God Only Knows Season 2, Elsie types something like a game, but her first try is wrong.

This is a picture of what she type:

[image: yuute imiya oukimu]

What did it says? And how can she mistype that? It looks really different with the right one, which is 'kami nomi zo shiru sekai' (神のみぞ知るセカイ), but I don't know anything about Japanese so I might be wrong and Google translate didn't help much...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the Dragon Quest 2 log in screen (hence the DQ2 password).
The first thing she types in is a resurrection spell from the Dragon Quest series

> The Spell of Restoration (復活の呪文, ふっかつのじゅもん, fukkatsu no jumon) is the name of the password system used in the Famicom and MSX versions of Dragon Quest and Dragon Quest II. Similar to other games of the time, the player's accomplishments were converted into a password, which was then written down and entered later to resume the game from the point at which the player left off. With the advent of battery backup (first seen in the series in Dragon Quest III), password systems became obsolete, and the Spell of Restoration was never used again. **It differs from the passwords of other games in that it is recognized by some characters as a convention of the game world and not simply a means of resuming gameplay.**

"Kami nomi zo shiru sekai" follows the same pattern used, which is 3-3-4:

- Ka-mi-no
- mi-zo-shi
- ru-se-ka-i

[image]

> Dragon Quest II
>
> Due its broader scope (three-member party, multiple flagged plot events, and a wider array of equipment), Dragon Quest II employed a larger 52-character Spell of Restoration: Four lines of 3-3-4, followed by a final line of 3-3-4-2.

As to why she mistypes, it is most likely a reference to the fact you load a life. A life only you know of, hence *The world god only knows*, Keima's world.

Answer (score 2):

[Dimitri mx's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/7641/25160) has explained about the origin of the screen: it is *Dragon Quest 2*'s password input screen.

As to why she mistypes, the input was actually part of a real, valid *DQ2* password that's famous for its effect (in short: [new game plus (Japanese YouTube link)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VC4Yg85lU0o)):

```
ゆうて　いみや　おうきむ
こうほ　りいゆ　うじとり
やまあ　きらぺ　ぺぺぺぺ
ぺぺぺ　ぺぺぺ　ぺぺぺぺ
ぺぺぺ　ぺぺぺ　ぺぺぺぺ　ぺぺ

YUUTE  IMIYA  OUKIMU
KOUHO  RIIYU  UJITORI
YAMAA  KIRAPE PEPEPEPE
PEPEPE PEPEPE PEPEPEPE
PEPEPE PEPEPE PEPEPEPE PEPE
```

It needs proper spacing to understand the background of the password:

```
ゆうて　　い■みや　おう■きむ
こう■ほ　りいゆ　　うじ■とり
やまあ　　きら ...

YUUTE  I|MIYA OU|KIMU
KOU|HO RIIYU  UJI|TORI
YAMAA  KIRA ...
```

1. ゆうてい/ゆう帝 (*yuu tei*): Pen name for one of *Weekly Shonen Sunday*'s game introduction corner staff.
2. みやおう/ミヤ王 (*miya ou*): (same as above)
3. きむこう/キム皇 (*kimu kou*): (same as above)
4. ほりいゆうじ/堀井雄二 (*horii yuuji*): Yuutei's real name
5. とりやまあきら/鳥山明 (*toriyama akira*): *Dragon Quest*'s character designer

<sup>It's also parodied in *Dragon Quest 11* ([Japanese YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhUw1dXaX8o)) and *Gamers!* (light novel, volume 2, chapter 6).</sup>

---

Source: [Dragon Quest wikiwiki (Japanese)](http://wikiwiki.jp/dqdic3rd/?%A1%DA%A4%E6%A4%A6%A4%C6%A4%A4%A4%DF%A4%E4%A4%AA%A4%A6%A4%AD%A4%E0%A4%B3%A4%A6%A1%C4%A1%DB)